# C# if statement true cancel the remaining process

Tags: c#, messagebox, isnullorempty

I have an if statement that checks if a textbox is not empty. HOwever, if it True, meaning empty i want it to cancel the rest of the process and go back to my form. Below is the IF statement that i have, i cant figure out how to Cancel the remainder of the process.

```
if (textBox2.Text.Equals(""))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Field is Empty", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Comment: What process do you want to cancel?

Comment: " i want it to cancel the rest of the process and go back to my form" where are you now?

Comment: What is your Process? you just show an If statement. What specifically are you wanting to exit/cancel?

Comment: If you mean that after that message box is showed you just want to stop execution of the outer method, just call `return`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did mean stop execution, just didnt know the wording. Thats exactly what i wanted!! Thanks @OndrejJanacek

Comment: I provided also an answer so that the question can be closed by marking a working/correct solution as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a method like

```
DoSomething();
```

causes it to start executing whatever is inside. In some point, if you no longer wish to continue in execution of that method call, use `return` statement with no return value for methods returning void or `return something` for methods with non-void return type, where `something` is type of the return type.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   ... do something
   if (condition)
      return; // returns from a method call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/1dac1663%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
private void validateUserEntry2()
{
    // Checks the value of the text.
    if(serverName.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        // Initializes the variables to pass to the MessageBox.Show method.

        string message = "You did not enter a server name. Cancel this operation?";
        string caption = "No Server Name Specified";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogResult result;

        // Displays the MessageBox.

        result = MessageBox.Show(this, message, caption, buttons,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
            MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);

        if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Closes the parent form.
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```